# Is the first white walker also the Night King?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We have seen the first white walker, created by the the children of the forest.

[image: the first white walker, created by the the children of the forest]

We also see a white walker who was supposed to be the Night King several times.

[image: Night King]

Based on their faces, can they be the same person? I know the best canon explanation for the Night King is him being the 13th Lord Commander of the Night's Watch, however, this can easily be a red herring.

Any canon evidence, supporting/disproving the first white walker being the Night King is also welcome. Although the images are from the series, book explanations are also welcome.

EDIT: Actually my question is very different and focused compared to the differences between books and show. It is already somewhat answered, both characters played by the same person.

Comment: It's the same actor, which is why the faces look so similar. However, based on [the actor's IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0298842/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t37#actor) that's his only acting credit (on Game of Thrones), and he's primarily a stunt performer on the show. I don't think the fact they recycled an actor is enough to prove that the first White Walker and the Night King are the same.

Comment: We don't know for sure, as [Aegon's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129072/70236) suggests.

Comment: Actually there are two Night Kings. But although I agree that extras are recycled a lot, I don't think Night King is an extra, while first white walker might be.